# Java Runnable as argument evaluation

Tags: java, runnable

I am developing a client-server in java and I encountered problem passing a custom Runnable implementation as argument from an object to another.
The problem is that the Runnable code is evaluated (not executed) at definition but I want it to be evaluated at invocation.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Here the code affected by this problem:

- Custom Runnable implementation

```
public abstract class ChallengeReportDelegation implements Runnable
{
    private ChallengeReport fromChallengeReport = null;
    private ChallengeReport toChallengeReport = null;

    @Override
    public abstract void run();

    public ChallengeReport getFromChallengeReport()
    {
        return fromChallengeReport;
    }

    public ChallengeReport getToChallengeReport()
    {
        return toChallengeReport;
    }

    public void setFromChallengeReport(ChallengeReport fromChallengeReport)
    {
        this.fromChallengeReport = fromChallengeReport;
    }

    public void setToChallengeReport(ChallengeReport toChallengeReport)
    {
        this.toChallengeReport = toChallengeReport;
    }
}
```

- Here where the Runnable is passed as argument:

```
// Record challenge
this.challengesManager.recordChallenge(whoSentRequest, whoConfirmedRequest,
                            new ChallengeReportDelegation()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    ChallengeReport fromReport = getFromChallengeReport();
                                    ChallengeReport toReport = getToChallengeReport();
                                    sendMessage(whoSentRequest, new Message(MessageType.CHALLENGE_REPORT, String.valueOf(fromReport.winStatus), String.valueOf(fromReport.challengeProgress), String.valueOf(fromReport.scoreGain)));
                                    sendMessage(whoConfirmedRequest, new Message(MessageType.CHALLENGE_REPORT, String.valueOf(toReport.winStatus), String.valueOf(toReport.challengeProgress), String.valueOf(toReport.scoreGain)));
                                }
                            });
```

- The receiving object store the `ChallengeReportDelegation` instance as `completionOperation`, wait for a timeout then execute this code.

```
private void complete()
    {
        stopTranslations();

        int fromStatus;
        int toStatus;
        if (this.fromScore > this.toScore)
        {
            fromStatus = 1;
            toStatus = -1;
        }
        else if (this.fromScore < this.toScore)
        {
            fromStatus = -1;
            toStatus = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fromStatus = 0;
            toStatus = 0;
        }

        this.completionOperation.setFromChallengeReport(new ChallengeReport(this.from, fromStatus,this.fromTranslationsProgress, this.fromScore));
        this.completionOperation.setToChallengeReport(new ChallengeReport(this.to, toStatus, this.toTranslationsProgress, this.toScore));
        this.completionOperation.run();
    }
```

The code above raises a `NullPointerException` at the execution of the last portion of code, in the run method.

[EDIT]

The `NullPointerException` exception is thrown because both `getFromChallengeReport()` and `getToChallengeReport()` (second portion of code) initially return null (when the Runnable is defined and passed as argument),
but they would return consistent values at invocation time `run()` (third portion of code)

[EDIT2]

I reproduced the situation in this simple code:

```
public class TestEvaluation
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Middle middle = new Middle();

        middle.register(new Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("a is: " +  getA());
                System.out.println("b is: " +  getB());
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    abstract static class Task implements Runnable
    {
        private int a = 0;
        private int b = 0;

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        abstract public void run();
    }

    static class Middle
    {
        private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

        public void register(Task task)
        {
            Leaf leaf = new Leaf(new Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Middle");
                    task.run();
                }
            });
            pool.schedule(leaf, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    static class Leaf implements Runnable
    {
        public Task task;

        public Leaf(Task task)
        {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            task.setA(5);
            task.setB(5);
            System.out.println("Leaf");
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior that i want to achieve is the printing of

```
Leaf
Middle
a is: 5
b is: 5
```

But this is what i get

```
Leaf
Middle
a is: 0
b is: 0
```

Comment: Your question is where is the NPE coming from? There's no way to tell from this information.

Comment: I tried to explain better. See last edit. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `getXXXChallengeReport()` methods are only called when `run()` is invoked, not when the `Runnable` is declared. Maybe show more complete code (it's not clear where the `this.challengesManager.recordChallenge()` is called, nor to what class `complete()` belongs). Have you stepped through this with breakpoints?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and include the full stack trace of the error(s).

Comment: @Slaw I provided simplified example to reproduce the problem ([EDIT2])

Comment: You have a task wrapped in a task. You set a and b of the outter task, but the original task a and b do not change. Are you trying to make this convoluted on purpose?

Comment: @matt You're right. I understood your reply and so the cause of the problem but anyway I can not get how to achieve the behavior I want. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Call setA and setB on the object you want to change a and b of.

Comment: Why not only use one instance of `Task` instead of wrapping one in another? What purpose does the second `Task` serve?

Comment: @Slaw In this context the second `Task` is useless of course but in my application happens some stuff where `System.out.println("Middle");` is placed

Comment: You could override the getters/setters of the wrapper task to delegate to the wrapped task. Or you could invoke the setters of the wrapped task when the wrapper task's setters are invoked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a working solution for this problem, perhaps trivial for those coming from functional programming.

Accordingly to the example in last edit ([EDIT2])

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TestEvaluation
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Middle middle = new Middle();

        middle.register(new Consumer<Values>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Values values) {
                System.out.println("a is: " +  values.getA());
                System.out.println("b is: " +  values.getB());
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    static class Values
    {
        private int a = 0;
        private int b = 0;

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    static class Middle
    {
        private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

        public void register(Consumer<Values> passed)
        {
            Consumer<Values> middleConsumer = new Consumer<Values>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Values values) {
                    System.out.println("Middle");
                    passed.accept(values);
                }
            };

            Leaf leaf = new Leaf(middleConsumer);
            pool.schedule(leaf, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    static class Leaf implements Runnable
    {
        public Consumer<Values> task;

        public Leaf(Consumer<Values> task)
        {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Values values = new Values();
            values.setA(5);
            values.setB(5);
            System.out.println("Leaf");
            task.accept(values);
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the behavior i want.
Hope this will help someone.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example. Lets create a runnable with a field.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    var x = new Runnable(){
        int a = 0;
        int getA(){
               return a;
        }
        void setA(int v){
            a = v;
        }
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("A : " + getA());
        }
    };
    x.run();
    x.setA(5);
    x.run();
}
```

The first time it is 0, the second time 5, because getA is evaluated when run is called.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to immediately evaluate something. I'd suggest not using a `Runnable` at all. It sound like an anti-pattern, trying to pass code around when all you want is the value/invocation.

Furthermore, try to use a Callable or Supplier instead since you are clearly interested in returning some values from the sub-routines.